# How do I get in to a Wrath of the Lich King Heroic?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm trying to get my Mechanohog and I was wondering if it is possible to get into a heroic Lich King Dungeon if you're level  85.

Answer (score 4):

It is. Simply right-click on your character portrait, and then change your dungeon difficulty (5 man) to heroic. When you enter a Wrath of the Lich King dungeon, it will be on heroic difficulty. Note that you'll have to physically enter the dungeon through the instance portal (which should have a skull in the display if you have the difficulty set to heroic).

Comment: Adding on: You have actually go to the dungeons location in Northrend and enter it there.  You can't queue for it.